# What is the best way to detect and extract article content / comments from blog's article

Tags: java, html, detection, article

I have blog post ([sample 1](http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2010/11/extending-eclipse-memory-analyzer.html), [sample 2](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/126912/)). What is the best way to parse HTML and detect author, title, date, **article content**, comments (separately). Whole other content should be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your blogsite has an RSS feed, you can use Java's SAX Parser to whip through the XML

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

Here's an example of someone parsing an RSS using a SAX Parser

http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/07/25/rss-parser-sax/

Answer (score 0):

You may not get everything you are looking for but I think [Boilerpipe](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) is worth looking at.